# Document.Ready function doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have username and password saved in cookies. My goal is to send that data to my server and then the server will send back response and I will display the response on my webpage. But before I do that I used alert() to see if it is working.

I think something is wrong with the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var messageType = "3";
    var cookie_name = "username";
    var cookie_name2 = "password";
    var YouWrote = getName(cookie_name);
    var YouWrote2 = getName2(cookie_name2);
    var userName = YouWrote;
    var password = YouWrote2;
    auth(messageType, userName, password);
});

function auth(messageType, userName, password) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //SEND TO SERVER URL
        url: "######",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: '{"messageType": "' + messageType + '", "userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',

        error: function (xhr, error) {
            alert('Error!');
        },

        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data.details + '\nHello ' + data.clientInfo.firstName + ' ' + data.clientInfo.lastName + '. \nBalance:' + data.clientInfo.balance);
        }
    })
}
```

These two functions will help me get the cookie data saved (this works, I have tested it):

```
function getName() {
    if (document.cookie) {
        index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
        if (index != -1) {
            namestart = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
            nameend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
            if (nameend == -1) {
                nameend = document.cookie.length;
            }
            YouWrote = document.cookie.substring(namestart, nameend);
            return YouWrote;
        }
    }
}

function getName2() {
    if (document.cookie) {
        index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name2);
        if (index != -1) {

            namestart = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
            nameend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
            if (nameend == -1) {
                nameend = document.cookie.length;
            }
            YouWrote2 = document.cookie.substring(namestart, nameend);
            return YouWrote2;
        }
    }
}
```

I turned my server off on purpose because I want to see if it will show alert("Error!"). It doesn't which means the functions aren't running properly in the document.ready.

Is there an obvious issue that I'm missing? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: did you check your javascript console for any errors?

Comment: no errors. its just not working.

Comment: Please adjust the indentations of the functions for better display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions will need to have input argument specified:

```
function getName(cookie_name){ ... };


function getName2(cookie_name2){  ... };
```

Comment: wow im dumb. I have coded so much in the past and even thought I am new to HTML (kind of), this is something I should know.

Thanks a lot. Now it works perfect!

Comment: Weird is that sometimes its not needed.... I think I have used functions like this in the past where I didnt use the input arg.

Comment: The function must have been in the same scope as the variable in that case. But, above code, notice that the functions are pulled out of the scope of the variable "cookie_name"s